# ggplot2: object 'y' not found with stat="bin"

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm sorry to ask a question that has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974666/ggplot2-stacked-bar-chart-object-y-not-found) on SO, but I'm trying to plot some [simple data](https://douglas-duhaime.squarespace.com/s/cleaned_estc_visuals.txt)  in ggplot2 and am having trouble binning the data along the x-axis. My data consists of visual elements in old books (diagrams, engravings, etc.), and I can plot the frequency of each type of visual element in each year:

```
#this works
df <- read.table("cleaned_estc_visuals.txt",
                 header = F,
                 sep = "\t")

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=V1, y=V3)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=V2),stat="identity") +
  labs(title = "Visuals in Early Modern Books",fill="") +
  xlab("Year") + 
  ylab("Titles")
```

This yields:
[image]

To make the data more legible, I want to bin the values along the x-axis by decade, but can't quite seem to get the call right:

```
#this doesn't
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=V1, y=V3)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=V2),binwidth=10,stat="bin")
```

Running the latter code, I get:

```
Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin".
  With stat="bin", it will attempt to set the y value to the count of cases in each group.
  This can result in unexpected behavior and will not be allowed in a future version of ggplot2.
  If you want y to represent counts of cases, use stat="bin" and don't map a variable to y.
  If you want y to represent values in the data, use stat="identity".
  See ?geom_bar for examples. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.2)
Error in pmin(y, 0) : object 'y' not found
```

Does anyone know how I can bin by decade along the x-axis? I would be grateful for any advice others can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, I find it easier to do some data manipulation before calling `ggplot()`. I personally prefer these packages: `dplyr` for data management and `scales` for working with graphics, but you could do this using `base` functions as well.

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(decade = floor(V1 / 10) * 10) %>% 
  group_by(decade, V2) %>%
  summarise(V3 = sum(V3)) %>%
  filter(decade != 1800)


ggplot(df2, aes(x = decade, y = V3)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = V2), stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Decade", y = "Titles", title = "Visuals in Early Modern Books") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(20)) # using scales::pretty_breaks()
```

Comment: This looks great, @DMC! The edited code is more legible; thanks for those changes. Just a quick question: Is there an easy way to remove the final bar? I believe it's summing 1800:1810, and because there's only one year within that range (1800), it could potentially be deceiving. Would I call `which` on the df call in line 1 of your code?

Comment: And that last group would be summing years 1800-1809 (not 1800-1810)